# How can I build a <select> with multiline options in Ng-Zorro

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I use The Ng-Zorro in Angular Project

I have problem with long text in select/option that it has showed in picture

[image]

- Long text must show in multiline
- horizontal scroll bar must be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle it with CSS styles:

change `white-space` for `ant-select-option-content`

```
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  white-space: unset;
}
```

Working demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udgu25)